# Laravel Edit Form - Select Box - Old Value or database value selected on form load/submit

Tags: database, laravel, select, box

I'm trying to create an edit form for my laravel application that shows a list of damage types.

When the form loads, I want to have the value from the database selected (i.e. $device_destroyed[0]->damage_type)

However if the user submits the form and  there are validation errors, I want the old value to be selected instead.

I've tried many different conditions but can't seem to get the logic right. I want to avoid duplicate values being displayed in the select options as well.

Hopefully the below might give an idea of what I'm trying to do:

```
          <select id="damage_type" name="damage_type">
              <option value="">Please Select</option>

              @for ($i = 0 ; $i < count($damage_types); ++$i)
                  <option value="{{ $damage_types[$i] }}"

                      @if(old('damage_type') == $damage_types[$i]) 
                          selected
                      @endif

                      @if($damage_types[$i] == $device_destroyed[0]->damage_type)
                          selected
                      @endif
                            
                  >{{ $damage_types[$i]}}
                  </option>   
              @endfor

         </select>
```

[image: List of select damage options]

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Adrian Edy Pratama
for helping arrive at the solution.

Without the extra `!($errors->any())` parameter in the elseif condition block, two select options were being selected.

The final solution was:

```
@if($errors->any() && old('damage_type') == "$damage_types[$i]")
    selected
@elseif(!($errors->any()) && ($damage_types[$i] == $device_destroyed[0]->damage_type))
    selected
@endif
>{{ $damage_types[$i]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@if($errors->any() && old('damage_type') == $damage_types[$i])
    selected
@elseif($damage_types[$i] == $device_destroyed[0]->damage_type)
    selected
@endif
```

Comment: Thanks. This sort of works but only if a value underneath the original value is selected. 

E.g. in the image provided above, If screen is selected on form load and I select "Test", "Test" stays stays selected after form validation. 

But if I select "Battery" which is above "Screen", the value selected after validation is "Screen" again.

I think it may have something to do with the for loop and the fact that not all of the elements are loaded when the conditions are checked.

Comment: You already use the `@elseif` right? make sure it's not print 2 selected in the same time